# how to use cdn javascript files on mvc 5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I am using a template i bought from themeforest in my mvc 5 application, everthing is working fine except whenever i want to include some external javascript files that didnt come with the template, then the javascript would not see the javascript that came with the template anymore! below is my code:

BundleConfig.cs:

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Javascript",
                       @"//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
                       ).Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Javascript",
                       @"//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"
                       ).Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/all.css"));          

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Javascript").Include(
            "~/DataTables-1.10.10/media/js/jquery.js",
            "~//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js",
            "~/DataTables-1.10.10/media/js/jquery.js",
            "~/DataTables-1.10.10/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/all.css",               
            "~/Content/themes/base/base.css",                
            "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css",               
            "~/Content/themes/base/tabs.css",               
            "~/Content/themes/base/tooltip.css"));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        bundles.UseCdn = true;
    }
```

_Layout.schtml:

```
 <head>
    <title>Farm Management System</title>
    <!-- start: META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content="IE=edge,IE=9,IE=8,chrome=1" /><![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
    <!-- end: META -->


    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")




    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/JavaScript")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".jqueryui-marker-datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: "button"
            }).css("display", "inline-block")
                .next("button").button({
                    icons: { primary: "ui-icon-calendar" },
                    label: "Select a date",
                    text: false
                });
        });
    </script>



    @RenderSection("Scripts", required : false)



    <!-- start: MAIN CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/fonts/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/css/main-responsive.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/plugins/iCheck/skins/all.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-colorpalette/css/bootstrap-colorpalette.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/perfect-scrollbar.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/css/theme_light.css" type="text/css" id="skin_color"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />



    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- end: MAIN CSS -->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />


    <!-- start: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="~/assets/plugins/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/assets/plugins/excanvas.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/plugins/jQuery-lib/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/jQuery-lib/2.0.3/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/iCheck/jquery.icheck.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/jquery.mousewheel.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/src/perfect-scrollbar.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/less/less-1.5.0.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-colorpalette/js/bootstrap-colorpalette.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/js/main.js")"></script>


    <!-- end: MAIN JAVASCRIPTS -->

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            Main.init();
            Index.init();
            FormElements.init();
            FormValidator.init();
            UIButtons.init();
            //TableData.init();
        });
    </script>


    @RenderSection("CSS", required : false)
    @RenderSection("JavaScript", required : false)



</head>
```

Content.cshtml:

```
@section JavaScript
{
    <!-- start: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
            $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
        });
    </script>
    <!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
}

@section CSS
     {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes /smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
}
```

Now on this page, the side menu and menu bar items from _Layout Page no longer working, please, i will appreciate if anyone could show me how to do it right.

Comment: In the CSS section of `Content.cshtml`, there is a space after `themes` in the stylesheet path. Is that correct?

Comment: You already have `jquery` and `jquery-ui` included in `_Layout`, why you are trying to add them again?

Comment: @Jamie, there is no space, css works fine.

Comment: @Arghya, please at which point am i adding them again?

Comment: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>` the http part is missing though.

Comment: Ok, you mean i should remove this from bundleConfig.cs file? even when i didnt add it to the bundleConfig.cs, i wasnt still working.

Comment: @ArghyaC: It's perfectly valid to omit the http/https part of the URL. A URL beginning with `//` means "use the same protocol as the page this is loaded on is using".

Comment: @ChrisPratt right. That's why it works for OP. I'd say it's good mention is explicitly, so that it works always. I agree, *"missing"* wasn't the right word though.

Comment: It's debatable. Although, given that there's less and less of a reason to use anything but HTTPS, nowadays, especially with Google Search starting to favor secure sites, you can probably just always use https rather than leaving it undetermined. If the site isn't https, it's not going to hurt anything to use scripts from a secure site.

Answer (score 0):

`~/bundles/Javascript` is declared three times. I'm not sure of the order of ops in terms of whether first or last defined wins, but you're only going to get one. Each of your bundle declarations should have a unique name.

Comment: i have remove other references, remaining only one, still not working